# How to migrate Tarantool tables in the presence of foreign keys?

Tags: tarantool

I want to migrate a Tarantool table to a different format. Currently (Tarantool 2.8), this must be done manually, by creating a new table, copying the data over, dropping the old table and renaming the new table to the old name. That also means dropping all foreign keys referencing the old table and creating new ones. But an unrelated limitation is that I can't create foreign keys on tables unless those tables are also empty.

Is there any way to solve this other than just not using foreign keys at all?

EDIT: I suppose I could emulate FKs with triggers. Are there any limitations with triggers that would make such emulation impossible?

Comment: found a ticket related to this github.com/tarantool/tarantool/issues/3699 the fact that it's from 2018 makes me think that nobody at VK actually use foreign keys at all.

Comment: NB: Foreign keys are implemented recently, see https://github.com/tarantool/doc/issues/2628.